# Is it possible to give an application direct access to a file?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Google Console has "service accounts" and service accounts can be given write permissions to files. These files can then modified without any sort of user intervention and works as long as the service account has the appropriate permissions.

Is there anything similar for Microsoft Graph? We have a file in a SharePoint folder that we would like continued access to even if the people with access to that folder continuously changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD has a notion of [Service Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects) that can be used for this purpose.